# SAS DIP Service failing to run

Tags: server, sas, metadata, scheduler

SAS Service "SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] Distributed In-Process Scheduler command-line job runner" is failing to run on Win2012 R2 server.

Its set to Automatic, failed to run on startup and fails now as I try to start it.
Only dependency is the SAS Metadata Server and that is running fine.

In the log at \Lev1\Web\Applications\SASWIPSchedulingServices9.4\dip\serviceLog, the entry reads:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2017/08/29 16:51:51 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2017/08/29 16:51:51 | Launching a JVM...
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2017/08/29 16:51:51 | Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2017/08/29 16:51:51 |     "\bin\java.exe" -Djava.system.class.loader=com.sas.app.AppClassLoader -Dsas.app.repository.path="D:\SAS\SASVersionedJarRepository\eclipse" -Dsas.app.launch.picklist="D:\SASConfig\Lev1\Web\Applications\SASWIPSchedulingServices9.4\dip/picklist" -Xmx128m -Dsas.cache.locators=rad1sas1.hps-rad.local[41415] -Dspring.profiles.active=client-locators -Dsas.gemfire.log-level=severe -Dsas.gemfire.log.file= -Djava.library.path="D:\SASConfig\Lev1\Web\Applications\SASWIPSchedulingServices9.4\dip" -classpath "D:\SAS\SASVersionedJarRepository\eclipse\plugins\JavaServiceWrapper_3.2.3\wrapper.jar;D:\SAS\SASVersionedJarRepository\eclipse\plugins\sas.launcher.jar" -Dwrapper.key="eknAd40L52PNah3_" -Dwrapper.port=32006 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=14260 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 com.sas.scheduler.api.servers.ip.engine.mq.client.JobRunnerService "D:\SASConfig\Lev1\Web\Applications\SASWIPSchedulingServices9.4\dip/DIPJobRunner.properties"
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2017/08/29 16:51:51 | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
```

Comment: Did you do a Java update on the server recently?

Comment: are the paths in the that Java command correct?

Comment: No Java updates recently @Reeza

Comment: "\bin\java.exe" looks fishi and I am checking.  We have recently applied SAS Hotfixes ( no jre update in it), looking into other log files @DomPazz

Answer (score 1):

It seems DIP job uses a configuration file sitting at SASHOME
D:\SAS\wrapper.conf

As @DomPazz pointed out the java path was incomplete while assigned to key. I 
included the full path and that solved the issue. Strangely, the First time I modified and restarted the box it got overwritten by a backup of the file sitting somewhere.

Contents of the wrapper.conf :

```
        # Java Application
        # In Error state the key below had the value of "\bin\java.exe" 
 wrapper.java.command=D:\SAS\SASPrivateJavaRuntimeEnvironment\9.4\jre\bin\java.exe

        # Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
        # needed starting from 1
        wrapper.java.classpath.1=D:\SAS\SASVersionedJarRepository\eclipse\plugins\JavaServiceWrapper_3.2.3\wrapper.jar
        wrapper.java.classpath.2=D:\SAS\SASVersionedJarRepository\eclipse\plugins\sas.launcher.jar

        # Java Additional Parameters
        wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.system.class.loader=com.sas.app.AppClassLoader
        wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dsas.app.repository.path="D:\SAS\SASVersionedJarRepository\eclipse"
```

**Note** : Another wrapper.conf sits in D:\SASConfig\Lev1\Web\Applications\SASWIPSchedulingServices9.4\dip but that seems have properties for the Windows service!